# OpenSSL for android

Tags: android, ssl, openssl

I am using following [OpenSSL library for android](https://github.com/guardianproject/openssl-android)

My application need to support TLS 1.2 version(TLSv2).I want to know Does above library support TLS 1.2 and above library is build upon which Openssl version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the code this is only OpenSSL 1.0.0a. TLS1.2 support was added with OpenSS L1.0.1, so this library does not support TLS1.2. BTW, TLS1.2 is TLSv1_2 and not TLSv2.

Answer (score 0):

> I am using following OpenSSL library for android

According to Steffen, its a dwonlevel version. You might consider building it yourself. You can find information on OpenSSL's wiki: [OpenSSL and Android](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android).

Or, you could fetch 1.0.1h from this Github: [Noloader GitHub](https://github.com/noloader?tab=repositories). The GitHub has OpenSSL 1.0.1h built for both API 14 (GCC 4.6 toolchain) and API 18 (GCC 4.8 toolchain).

> Does OpenSSL library support TLS 1.2 and above library is build upon which Openssl version?

If you are working with a modern version of OpenSSL, then TLS 1.2 will be available by default (unless on a distro like Debian and Ubuntu, which disables TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.2 prior to about 2014). If the distro has not disabled the protocol, then you should perform the following to tighten up the protocols:

```
/* Useless return value ??? */
SSL_library_init();

const SSL_METHOD* method = SSLv23_method();
if(!(NULL != method)) handleFailure();

SSL_CTX* ctx = SSL_CTX_new(method);
if(!(ctx != NULL)) handleFailure();

/* Cannot fail ??? */
const long flags = SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2 | SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3 | SSL_OP_NO_COMPRESSION;
SSL_CTX_set_options(ctx, flags);
```

The code above provides you with TLS 1.0 and above. You will be fine with TLS since its ubiquitous (hence, no need for SSLv3). The code will also ensure TLS 1.3 is available once its standardized (the IETF is standardizing it now). And it disables compression because of attacks like [CRIME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRIME).

There's also an opportunity to tighten up the cipher suites. You should provide 16 or 20 or so approved ciphers and no more. There's no reason to be using export grade ciphers, RC4 or MD5 in 2014. Plus, if you advertise all 80+ ciphers, it causes some appliances to break like older F5's and IronPorts. The applicances used a fixed-size buffer that was too small, and they choke/hang on the `ClientHello`.